# Is it possible for a website to hide parts from beautiful soup while scraping?

Tags: python, web-scraping, web

I have encountered a problem while trying to scrape a website with the python package beautiful soup. Somehow I am getting everything from it exept that part I am interested in. I am trying to scrape the realtime data from this site https://www.bitfinex.com/.

I really get every part exept for the realtime data and I think it is somehow connected to the script block inside the the same container as the data is. Firefox and Chrome can examine this part easy but beautiful soup somehow doesn't get it.

I'm grateful for every advice!

Comment: Are you using `requests`? `beautifulsoup` and `requests` can only handle static html, for javascript generated content you could use `selenium` together with PhantomJS, for example.
Also, bitfinex probably has an API that would make this job a lot easier for you.

Comment: I'll try that thanks! I can't register so I have to do it this way until I can make an account.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, yes, it is possible for a website to block or remove contents from anything that it suspects is a bot or any type of connection that it deems fit.
If you haven't set a user-agent, try that.
Without knowing what you've already tried, it's difficult to give advice on how to proceed.

Comment: I am past the redirection so I get the websites content now but this script part is not displayed as in chrome or firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the [API](https://docs.bitfinex.com/docs)?

Many websites do detect and block spiders that are scraping for data. Moreover, your scraper will break every time they update their UI.

The realtime data on BitFinex is probably populated by Javascript over AJAX after the page loads.

Comment: They currently don't allow new registrations so I can't make a wallet and can't get api keys. And I wanted to test my tradebot and simulate transactions with the realtime data.

Comment: An I am past that detection they redirected me at first but I was able to find a workaround.

Comment: Nah I can't help you violate their terms of use. Scraping their screens like that is probably a violation of their terms of use.